# Error running Python script from Applescript

Tags: python, shell, applescript

Why doesn't this work?

Applescript:

```
set script_path to "$HOME/Desktop"
do shell script "python & script_path & hello_world.py"
```

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """\
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Python - Hello World</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  Hello World
 </body>
</html>
```

"""

Errors:

> tell current application  do shell script "python & script_path &
>   hello_world.py"       --> error "sh: script_path: command not found sh:
>   hello_world.py: command not found" number 127 Result: error "sh:
>   script_path: command not found sh: hello_world.py: command not found"
>   number 127

Comment: Is that really how you concatenate in AppleScript? I'd guess that that runs `python` in the background, `script_path` in the background, and `hello_world.py`. (The latter two don't exist.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersands concatenate the string literals and variable substitutions. Like so:

```
set script_path to "$HOME/Desktop"
do shell script "python " & script_path & "/hello_world.py"
```

You also need a slash before hello_world.py or at the end of $HOME/Desktop. The example above shows it before hello_world.py.